# Finding number of ways to invest with OGF

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 5 different stocks. You have $20,000 to invest in them. But you can only invest in multiples of 1000, and not all the money can be put into  one stock. How many ways can you invest the 20,000?

This is a problem from a generating functions book. I know that I need to compute the Ordinary Generating Function for the number of ways to invest, but I have no clue how to do that. Can someone please help me or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = 1 + x^{1000} + x^{2000} + \cdots + x^{19000}$. Show that the answer is the coefficient of $x^{20000}$ in $(f(x))^5$.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Do you happen to know how to solve this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388948/exponential-generating-function-for-strings-of-length-n-with-a-constraint